# How should I create half-day events in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, calendar, icalendar

I'm creating an app in Rails that is essentially a holiday management tool. Employee requests holiday; email sent to manager for approval; manager approves/rejects etc.

The app will allow whole or half-day holidays to be taken and I'm wondering about the best way to handle the half-days. I don't want to present the user with a time picker. I would prefer to offer a date-picker and AM/PM checkboxes.

I suppose I'm looking for opinion on whether I should 1) use the chosen date in conjunction with say the AM checkbox to create a DateTime entry in the DB e.g. leave starts on 10 February in the AM = "2011-02-10 00:00" or 2) should I simply record a Date in the DB with a string reference to AM in a separate field.

I want to output leave in the form of .ics files and a stream so the first option to me makes the most sense but is likely to create a real fudge in the code. Any thoughts or further options appreciated.

Thanks

Robin

Answer (score 0):

Why not create durations (pairs of datetimes) for every holiday rather than just one? That should model the ical representation better than just storing single times as events.

---

As far as how to handle that at the view level, you're probably going to want to use the Presenter Pattern since you're really manipulating events rather than times.

A presenter is basically a proxy with added business logic that represents a better mapping for how the view interacts with the model.

It's a lightweight layer (they're normally just normal Ruby classes, rather than AR::Base or other heavyweight rails models) that wrap your models, and are usually instantiated at the controller level, and passed to your views rather than the model themselves.

http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/09/rails-model-view-controller-presenter.html
  http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/03/rails-presenter-pattern.html
  http://www.slideshare.net/adorepump/presenting-presenters-on-rails

---

Here's what I mean: https://gist.github.com/984025

Comment: Hopefully that helps. Obviously that's not my first take, I refactored it a couple times.